# ms-access listbox weirdness (memory issue?)

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access, vba

i have a huge sql query that is attached to the rowsource of a listbox.

the SQL statement seen here:

[ms-access: select from another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358642/ms-access-select-from-another-query)

actually returns the correct information if that information is under 2 records.

however if it returns more than 2 records it still populates the listbox but it populates it with null values. when i right click on one of the values and press COPY, it gives me this message:

"there isnt enough memory to retrieve data for the list box"

Comment: I think you need to work on the query to make sure you reduce the un-necessary JOINs and tighten the conditions.

Comment: do you think the join can be causing memory issues?

Comment: Try running the query & see, how it performs? Access re-runs or refreshes the query every time esp. when it is databound to some control.

Comment: i cant run it because i need to combine into one to run

Comment: Access does *not* refresh the recordsources of combo boxes and listboxes multiple times -- it loads it when the form is loaded, or when the rowsource is loaded. In order to alter the recordset returned, you have to requery in code -- it doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But does the query work if it is run separately?   And is the number of columns in the query the same number of columns as you've specified in the listbox Column Count property?

In your reply you state that you have to combine it?  Why?  Basic trouble shooting is to see if you can run the query separate from the lixtbox.

Comment: i get a data type mismatch on criteria expression error if i run it from the query view

Comment: btw i can run the USERS query without a problem

Comment: Data type mismatch?  Excellent.  Fixing that may very well solve the listbox wierdness problems.  One thing to check is the field type of the chavrusas.luser_id field.  If it's numeric then remove the single quotes around '3166'.

Comment: should the column count be exactly the number of columns or is it ok to have more

Comment: It's better to have the column count the same.   This might not make a difference now but this was a problem years ago in previous versions of Access.

Comment: btw. if you have to use that same query somewhere else, you could always make a second query the selects everything from the first, and has ONLY the columns you need.